# delete item from store redux

Tags: reactjs, state, react-redux

I am trying to remove an item from the redux store. When I delete the item from the UI, I get the error "cannot read property CourseId of undefined". The error is coming from the DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS action of the reducer when I try to use filter to remove the item.

Here is my API

```
static deleteCourse(course) {
    if (course.CourseId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              let url = '/api/courses/delete/' + course.CourseId;
              fetch(url, {
                  method: 'post',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  credentials: 'include',
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  headers : {
                    'Accept':'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }
              }).then((response) => {
                  if (response.ok === true)
                    return response;
              }).catch(function(err) {
                  alert('Error: ' + err);
              });

              resolve(course);
            }, delay);
        });
    } 
}
```

And my Action:

```
export function deleteCourseSuccess(course) {
    return { type: types.DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS, course };
}

export function deleteCourse(course) {
    return function(courseDispatch, getState) {
        courseDispatch(beginAjaxCall());
        return courseApi.deleteCourse(course).then(deletedCourse => {
            courseDispatch(deleteCourseSuccess(deletedCourse));
        }).catch(error => {
            courseDispatch(ajaxCallError(error));
            throw(error);
        });
    };
}
```

Here is my Reducer:

```
export default function courseReducer(state = initialState.courses, action) {
    switch(action.type) {

        case types.LOAD_COURSES_SUCCESS:
            return action.courses;

        case types.CREATE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
            return [
                ...state,
                Object.assign({}, action.course) 
            ];

        case types.UPDATE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
            return [
                ...state.filter(course => course.CourseId !== action.course.CourseId),
                Object.assign({}, action.course)
            ];

        case types.DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
            return [
                //  this is where the error occurs, says that course is undefined
                ...state.filter(course => course.CourseId !== action.course.CourseId)
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Here is the delete method in the component:

```
deleteCourse(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({deleting: true});
    this.props.actions.deleteCourse(this.state.course)
        .then(() => this.redirect())
        .catch(error => {
            toastr.error('deleteCourse:' + error);
            this.setState({deleting: false});
        });
}
```

If I just return ...state in the DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS action type, I don't get the error but the deleted item is still in the state. I know the item is in there too because I put the following alert before the return statement and saw it in there:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(state.filter(course => course.CourseId === action.course.CourseId)));
```

It is probably something simple I am missing but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

**Edit:** I found the culprit. In the component from where I am deleting the item, I have the following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.course.CourseId != nextProps.course.CourseId) {
        // necessary to populate form when existing course is loaded directly
        this.setState({course: Object.assign({}, nextProps.course)});
    }
}
```

When I commented this out, the error went away. It was "nextProps.course" that was undefined. Guess I better read up on react component lifecycles a little more instead of just blindly copying and pasting code :(

Comment: When you had your previous code up, I looked thru it and there was a function missing that I couldn't track down. You are showing the reducer, but you need to show the actionCreator. My guess is that you do not have the format like so, in the dispatch: {type: DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS, course: response.payload.datat}

Comment: oh, I shouldn't have removed the code. I'll put it back. I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: Where is this method? deleteCourseSuccess

Comment: let me get that on there

Comment: I feel that what you are giving your action is in a data format type you are not expecting. When you stringify it, it looks ok - but how it actually comes thru, not what you are expecting. Try this and see what you get. ...state.filter(course => console.log('course: ', course, 'action: ', action) || course.CourseId !== action.course.CourseId)